# Does Stan Lee have any creative control whatsoever over how his characters get used?

Tags: stan-lee

Just as the title asks; does Stan Lee have any creative control over his characters?

Case in point: I was watching [*Iron Man 3* (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1300854/) last night and was curious about the comic origin of The Mandarin.  So I looked it up online and discovered that, as his name might indicate, he was from China (as "Mandarin" is the name of the Chinese language).  Now, I get that terrorism is a hot topic these days, so having a terrorist be the "beard" for Killian sorta makes sense.  However, The Mandarin in the comics was apparently a really powerful character and a central foe of Iron Man, and in the movie his name doesn't even make sense!  The Mandarin is from the Middle East??

Does Stan Lee have the capability to say to writers, "No, you've gone too far off the mark with that", or has he lost complete control of how his characters are used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically...

## NO

> Stan Lee Media can’t claim ownership to any of the iconic comicbook characters Stan Lee created for Marvel, a federal court judge ruled Thursday, giving full control of superheroes like Spider-Man, The Avengers,  Iron Man, the Hulk, the Fantastic Four and the X-Men to the Walt Disney Co.
>
> ...
>
> Disney has said that Stan Lee Media failed to specify to which works it claims to own the copyright, instead referring “vaguely” to “comicbook characters…that (Lee) had previously created or would create.” It also added that Disney “is a holding company and as such does not conduct business in Colorado or anywhere else,” the company said in a motion to dismiss the suit. “There is no conceivable basis on which the plaintiff can state a viable copyright claim against (the Walt Disney Co.) in this court or, for that matter, any other.”
>
> <sup>[Source](http://variety.com/2013/biz/news/disney-wins-dismissal-of-stan-lee-medias-claim-for-marvels-superheroes-1200600641/)</sup>

Note that even though Stan Lee receives an Executive Producer credit this is *honorary*

> "I hate to admit this, but I do not share in the movie's profits," Lee told CNN.com in a recent interview. "I just share in the interviews, in the glamour, in the people saying, 'Wow, I love that movie, Stan' -- but I'm not a participant in the profits... [The executive producer credit] is an honorary title."
>
> <sup>[Source](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2012/05/15/how-much-did-stan-lee-make-on-the-avengers)</sup>

Comment: Looks like this came from a news article.  Can you dig up the date it was published?

Comment: It's at the link... 09/2013

Comment: Thanks!  I assume any subsequent retrials (assuming he didn't give up immediately) resulted in the same outcome?

Comment: That's covered in the article...he's basically out of appeals **and** as I recall, **he** is being sued for a share in the money he received for selling the *rights* in the first place.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee_Media

Comment: Do note that *"Stan Lee Media"* is NOT Stan Lee himself, like the Wikipedia link & [it's reference](https://icv2.com/articles/comics/view/24091/same-old-bs-dept-stan-lee-media-sues-again) says *"Back in 2007 Stan Lee Media, which has **also sued Stan Lee (who has long since cut all ties with the company)**..."* but it's pretty clear the character rights don't belong to Stan, or to Jack Kirby either. I saw a documentary about Marvel the other day and Todd McFarlane talked about Stan & Jack's treatment by Marvel was a warning to him to keep creative control of his characters